# Plotly Change mapbox cluster colors based on value

Tags: python, mapbox, plotly-dash

For a course I have been asked to visualize some data, to do this I'm trying to use Dash and Plotly, I'm using an airbnb data set and would like to plot them on a map to make it easier to understand, which I have done successfully. However I'm having trouble with the "cluster" function of the scatter_mapbox function, I have been able to have the data points cluster when zoomed out. Like in the image. But i would also like to be able to color those clusters in the same way that the individual data points are colored. Is this something that is possible? So far I've only found a way to give them a fixed color like in the screenshot but id like to change that color based on the points in that cluster. Any help would be appreciated.

Code for the plot:

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df_clean, lat="lat", lon="long",color="scaled", size="number of reviews", color_continuous_scale="aggrnyl_r")
fig.update_traces(cluster=dict(enabled=True, color="red", opacity=0.7))
```

If I don't directly supply a color to the clusters like I did here the clusters are invisible except for the number on them.

[The Clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqKNX.png)

[Two Data Points colored based on a value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzB7q.png)

I've tried googling but most of what I can find is about k-means clustering and the documentation doesn't seem to have much info on clustering on the scatter_mapbox function